# In the diagram, $ABCD$ is a rectangle, and $E$ is in the interior of the rectangle, find $DE$

Tags: geometry

[image]

How would I start this type of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Pythagorean theorem will give you $PE$ and $EQ$ in term of $x.$
Applied again you can find $y$
and again for $DE.$
And if you are lucky, the $x$ drops out along the way.